# "\Windows \system32\config\system" file may be missing or corrupted

Tags: windows, hard-drive-recovery

Something happened to my HP pavilion dv9000 and now when I try to start windows  I get this TeX on a   black screenc Windows could not start -/ Windows /system 32/config /system , is missing or is broken.   Tried system recovery by f11 without any  luck!   Perhaps you know a good command prompt -code for this kinda issues?   Regards Rebecka

Comment: That's where Windows saves the HKLM/System registry hive. Did you delete any registry by mistake? Try to solve it in safe mode or with sfc command with installation media.

Comment: I must have done SOMETHING wrong by misstake thats for sure! I dont have any  installation-tools because i bought the lap used top on internetafe. But im gonna give " safe mode" a try and hope for miracles! :D